# Improving Accuracy of iPhone's Accelerometer in Counting Steps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, navigation

I am currently using the following code to count the number of steps a user takes in my indoor navigation application. As I am holding the phone around my chest level with the screen facing upwards, it counts the number of steps I take pretty well. But common actions like a tap on the screen or panning through the map register step counts as well. This is very frustrating as the tracking of my movement within the floor plan will become highly inaccurate. Does anyone have any idea how I can improve the accuracy of tracking in this case? Any comments will be much appreciated! To have a better idea of what I'm trying to do, you guys can check out a similar Android application at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMgIa44mJXY. Thanks!

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

float xx = acceleration.x;
float yy = acceleration.y;
float zz = acceleration.z;

float dot = (px * xx) + (py * yy) + (pz * zz);
float a = ABS(sqrt(px * px + py * py + pz * pz));
float b = ABS(sqrt(xx * xx + yy * yy + zz * zz));

dot /= (a * b);
if (dot <= 0.9989) {
    if (!isSleeping) {
        isSleeping = YES;
        [self performSelector:@selector(wakeUp) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
        numSteps += 1;
    }
}  
px = xx; py = yy; pz = zz;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data from the accelerometer is basically a unidimensional (time) non uniform sampling of a three dimensional vector signal. The best way to figure out how to *count steps* will be to write an app that records and store the samples over a certain period of time, then export the data to a mathematical application like Wolfram's Mathematica for analysis and visualization. Remember that the sampling is non uniform, you may or may not want to transform it into a uniformly sampled digital signal.

Then you can try different signal processing algorithms to see what works best.

It's possible that, once you know the basic shape of a *step* in accelerometer data, you can recognize them by simple convolution.

Comment: Will it be easier to note that the phone will always be held in a fixed position? Can I simply consider the z component?

Comment: It will be easier as the function domain will reduce to a scalar instead of being a vector. But I have no idea if it will be sufficient to discern a _step_ from other kinds of motion. The whole point in using Mathematica or Matlab or similar, is to figure out what makes a step a step in terms of the signal shape. I suggest you record all three components and analyze the data. If the graphs you get from it suggest that only the z component is sufficient you can then use just that in the final implementation.

Comment: Do you know of any existing implementations regarding this problem?

Comment: I never had this problem, so I did never look for any existing implementation.